# How to insert/store a string value in influxdb measurement?

Tags: python, python-requests, influxdb

I am trying to insert some string value in influx db but keep getting 400 error. I am iusing python requests module to connect to influxdb. Here is my code:

```
description = '"' + some_str + '"'
payload = "%s, name=%s, description=%s, count=%d %d" %(measurement, name, description,count,timestamp)
requests.post(influx_uri, data=payload, headers= headers)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
400 {"error":"unable to parse 'sample,name=sample, description=\"some_str\", count=1 15106068120000000' : missing tag key"}
```

I don't know how this is getting generated `description=\"some_str\"`

Comment: Does this help you: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3600 ? Not a direct answer, but something similar.

Comment: I already checked that and it works well find if I take out the description field. Thanks Anyways @Grzegorg

Comment: sample is the measurement which is equivalent to table in relational database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. Another attempt.

By [reading the docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/write_protocols/write_syntax/) there's no mention of putting quotes around long strings. Instead they say you should escape spaces with a backslash:

> Escaping Characters
>
> If a tag key, tag value, or field key contains a space , comma ,, or
>   an equals sign = it must be escaped using the backslash character .
>   Backslash characters do not need to be escaped. Commas , and spaces
>   will also need to be escaped for measurements, though equals signs =
>   do not.

Moreover you shouldn't have spaces after commas. So I suggest you try:

```
description = "some\ str"
payload = "%s,name=%s,description=%s,count=%d %d" % (measurement, name, description,count,timestamp)
```

Comment: I am marking your answer correct but there are some changes required to make it work. There should be no space in between tags as it will throw tag error when introducing string. payload = "%s,name=%s,description=%s count=%d %d" % (measurement, name, description,count,timestamp)

Comment: some_str= some_str.replace(" ", "\ ")

Answer (score 0):

I have never used influxdb, to be honest it's the first time I hear of it, but...

By looking in the [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.8/api/reading_and_writing_data/) they seem to post a JSON content to the url using POST method, e.g.:

```
curl -X POST -d '[{"name":"foo","columns":["val"],"points":[[23]]}]' 'http://localhost:8086/db/mydb/series?u=root&p=root'
```

Your line doesn't look like a JSON document. And you better make it. Not sure what is your structure, but maybe this could do the job?

```
payload = """{"name":"%s", "description":"%s", "count":"%d %d"}""" %(name, description, count, timestamp)
```

Comment: No that is not working as it added more escaping in the payload. And it does not have to be json always https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/guides/writing_data/